# if statement issue with isinstance (or my coding)

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I keep hitting the else: portion of if statement
any integer or string I enter goes to else:

```
def isThisAnInteger(isInt):
    if isinstance(isInt, int):
        #return isInt
        print("Top of If: statement")
        print(isinstance(isInt, int))
    else:        
        #print("Please enter a valid number.")
        print("Bottom of else: statement")
        print(isinstance(isInt, int))

iStart = isThisAnInteger(input("Enter the start of the range: "))
iEnd = isThisAnInteger(input("Enter the end of the range: "))
```

I am expecting an integer to hit the first condition, while a string or float will fall to the else condition

Comment: `input()` always returns a string. This might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers

Comment: How are you checking for type in your function? If you're checking for `type` you can use the `type()`.

Comment: @MarceloPaco `isinstance` is the type-check that he is using. It allows you to check for classes that inherit from a certain (or multiple) classes.

Comment: @HampusLarsson my dyslexia kicked in. I thought they were recursively calling `isThisAnInteger`. Thanks for for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def isThisAnInteger(isInt: str):
    if isInt.isdigit():
        return int(isInt)
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid number.")

iStart = isThisAnInteger(input("Enter the start of the range: "))
iEnd = isThisAnInteger(input("Enter the end of the range: "))
```

Comment: Thanks Tourelou, That almost works, but when I put in a string like "b" it does not fall through to second condition (else:)  This was the message I got...        
in isThisAnInteger
    return int(isInt)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'b'

Comment: Sorry BigDog169, I forgot to put «()» after the «isdigit» call. It sould be read : `if isInt.isdigit():`

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Shouldnt the code blow up without the parens()?